# TransactionTooLargeException due to FragmentManagerState

Tags: android, androidx, android-architecture-navigation, fragmentmanager

I'm using Android Navigation Component for all navigation purposes in my App. Yet, I found out that the key "android:support:fragments" which stores the FragmentManagerState results in a TransactionTooLargeException after long usage of the app.

When I simply remove the key on persistence it works fine until a configuration change happens because then the app simply returns to the start fragment defined in the nav graph.

I was expecting that the state of the Nav Component is the "single source of truth".

Any idea to solve this conundrum?

Comment: The problem could be, you might be passing too much information in the fragment bundle. You could re-visit your design and find out the things you are passing to the bundle while creating the new instance of the fragment and if you find something which is too large, or has the potential to become large with the continuous usage of the app, and find another way to pass those information. Perhaps, load the data directly from DB when you fragment finished loading.

Comment: I solely pass uuids (as string) in my Bundles. No parcels, no images, nothing. All data are fetched from a Room database by these ids.